# How to check html code compatibility in phones for mobile phone web applications

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create an `HTML/Javascript` web page that will be compatible with web browsers on mobile phones, even with earlier versions of mobile phones still in circulation. The web page will employ select lists, buttons, links, and very basic `Javascript` for some variables.

1. Can I implement `JQuery` to enable a richer user interface.
2. Will its performance be acceptable on the intended earlier devices.
3. What is the safest versions (for compatibility) of HTML/Javascript/JQuery Mobile that i can consider for the content?

Comment: Define "earlier". Performance will depend on what you do with it.

Comment: You can take a look at jQuery Mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/

It depends on your definition of "earlier devices", do you think of early when thinking of i.e. Android 2.3 or do you even mean "Feature Phones"?

Comment: Start by looking into WAP - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Application_Protocol

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. Consider some mobile frameworks (your jquery-mobile example is great)
2. It really depends on what you intend to do. Big animations won't even run - [***check here***](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/)
3. If you're counting on default browsers in old platforms like windows mobile 6.X you can hardly expect your webpage to look good no matter what version you use. Those browsers really suck on html/javascript/CSS

Answer (score 0):

I can speak from experience when I tell you that even jQuery Mobile is horrendously slow on older phones (ie. pre-smartphone). If you are intending to target such devices, you will need to keep everything as simple as possible, especially since they don't have touchscreens so you have to navigate with the directional arrows...

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what you mean by older phones.

There are many older phones that do not support JavaScript, so if you want to support them, you can't use JavaScript - period.

If you want to only support phones that have at least support for JavaScript, use jQuery. Note that jQuery Mobile is optimised for touch enabled devices and is used mostly for such purposes.

If I were you I would simply go with plain JavaScript and limit the interactivity to simple content switches etc. and get rid of any animations.